# MySQL, select column name based on a value

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains the course number for training that needs to be done as column names. Each time a new training form is added a new column is created for it. A 0 stands for uncompleted and a 1 stands for completed.

I want to be able to get the course numbers (column names) for a specific person based on whether the value for the column is 1 (complete). So it would have to iterate through all the columns to check if they are 1. But I am not going to know the names of the columns beforehand since a script dynamically adds new course numbers to the table. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE Training(
id int NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
username varchar(6) not null,
`9875` INT(2) NULL,
`875` INT(2) NULL,
`475` INT(2) NULL,
`9835` INT(2) NULL,
`375` INT(2) NULL,
`9872` INT(2) NULL,
`9234` NULL,
`3444` NULL
);

INSERT INTO Training VALUES(kd4893,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0)
```

So a query on kd4893 would return 475,9835,9872,9234.

Would it be simpler to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your table, you can add the column names to a new array and join it

```
$res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from Training where username = 'kd4893'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

//printing the results
print_r($row);

$newrow = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($row as $key => $value){
    if($i > 1){
        if($value > 0){
            $newrow[] = $key;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

//printing the joined array
echo join(",",$newrow);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [username] => kd4893
    [9875] => 0
    [875] => 0
    [475] => 1
    [9835] => 1
    [375] => 0
    [9872] => 1
    [9234] => 1
    [3444] => 0
)

475,9835,9872,9234
```

This is no best way to do this, but is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Database normal form would require three tables:

- A user table. fields: `user_id, name`
- A course name table. fields:    `course_id, course_name`
- A cross reference table. fields: `user_id,   course_id`

This might be harder in the short run but worth it if you add many features.

If you want to stick with one table, why not:

one table: `user_name`, comma-separated string of course names.

Your insert becomes:

```
INSERT INTO Training VALUES(kd4893, "475,9835,9872,9234")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing out on a lot of the power of a relational database by trying to dynamically generate your data as columns instead of part of a record in a table.  By [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data, you can craft your database schema in such a way that it will enforce some rules for you:

- Course IDs must be unique.
- Student IDs must be unique.
- Students enrolled in courses must have a real StudentID, and courses must have a real CourseID.
- A student can't have multiple concurrent enrollments of a course.
- A student can only have one course status.

Example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Courses` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` varchar(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` varchar(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Enrolled` (
    `CourseID` INT NOT NULL,
    `StudentID` INT NOT NULL,  
    `Status` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CourseID`, `StudentID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`CourseID`) REFERENCES Courses (`ID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID`) REFERENCES Students (`ID`)
);
```

Now we can insert some data...

```
INSERT INTO Courses (ID, Name) VALUES (1, "Algebra 1");
INSERT INTO Courses (ID, Name) VALUES (2, "English");

INSERT INTO Students (ID, Name) VALUES (1, "Tom");
INSERT INTO Students (ID, Name) VALUES (2, "Tina");

INSERT INTO Enrolled (CourseID, StudentID, Status) VALUES (1, 1, 0);
INSERT INTO Enrolled (CourseID, StudentID, Status) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Enrolled (CourseID, StudentID, Status) VALUES (1, 2, 0);
```

...and query some sensible results.

Here is an example where we select the CourseID and CourseName for all courses that Tom has completed:

```
Select c.ID as CourseID, c.Name as CourseName
From Enrolled as e
Join Courses as c ON e.CourseID = c.ID
Join Students as s on e.StudentID = s.ID
Where s.ID = 1 AND e.Status = 1;

COURSEID    COURSENAME
2           English
```

Here's a sql fiddle with another query commented out.  Feel free to play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/126e5/3/1